# Reduce tailwind image to the smallest

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have added images on my page using tailwinds but on mobile, the image still appears to be bigger than I want.
My code below:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 py-3 px-6 border-b border-gray-300 overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="md:shrink-0">
            <img class="h-40 w-full scale-75 object-cover md:h-full md:w-48" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488998427799-e3362cec87c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Man looking at item at a store">
            </div>
            <div class="p-4">
            <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-light">Course</div>
            <a href="#" class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline">How to Organize Your Time and Your Life</a>
            <p class="mt-2 ">By: Pete Mockaitis | How to Be Awesome at Your Job</p>
            <span class="text-sm text-slate-500">134,768 Viewers. Released Jun 19, 2022</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**What I get**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to make a website responsive is by using `display: grid;`>. I think this solves your problem:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 py-3 px-6 border-b border-gray-300 overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">

    <img class="h-30 w-full col-span-1 object-cover md:h-full md:w-48" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488998427799-e3362cec87c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Man looking at item at a store">
  
<div class="col-span-2">
            <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-light">Course</div>
            <a href="#" class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline">How to Organize Your Time and Your Life</a>
            <p class="mt-2 ">By: Pete Mockaitis | How to Be Awesome at Your Job</p>
            <span class="text-sm text-slate-500">134,768 Viewers. Released Jun 19, 2022</span>
</div>

</div>
```